# Golang: strange behavior when debugging code that takes inputs

Tags: debugging, go, intellij-idea, input

I am considering this simple code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "os"

)
var in *bufio.Reader
var out io.Writer

func init() {
    in = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    out = os.Stdout
}

func main() {
    str, err := in.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println("str: ", str, "err: ", err)
}
```

I am using IntelliJ with the Go plugin. My version of Go is 1.8.
If I simply run the code there is no problem: str will be the same as the string I put, and err will be < nil >.
If I debug the code I will not have the chance to put anything as input and I will have the following output:

```
    API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:44824
    str:   err:  EOF
```

I have no idea of what is happening: what is the first line for? How is it generated? And why the terminal does not "block" to let me write the input? And why err is "EOF" (it is like the part in which I have to put text is simply skipped: why?) ?

Last additional detail: I am executing this simple piece of code because I am actually trying to understand what is happening in a bigger project, in which a similar issue occurs. In fact, in that case I still have to put something by hand, and, again, if I debug the code it returns an error. In this case, however, the err variable contains a different thing: "error".

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "If I debug the code". How do you "debug" the code?

Comment: that I run the code in debug mode, in such a way that I can set breakpoints, see the values of the variables, execute one instruction at a time (if I want to) etc.

Comment: Are you sure your debugger has stdin connected and if yes: To what?

Comment: Seems to be related to a delve issue : https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/65